# Blazor session storage - How to pass unknown type

Tags: types, reflection, local-storage, blazor-server-side

I would like to create a method to handle returning the objects in SessionStorage throughout my Blazor app.

The error I am getting of course is: ***'obj' is a variable but is used like a type***

Is there a way to use reflection or something to accomplish this? I have searched for an answer for hours.

```
public async Task<object?> GetFromStorageAsync(string key, object obj)
{
    try
    {
        var o = await PSession.GetAsync<obj>(_StorageKey);
        return (o.Success ? o.Value : null);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: Looks like this article is creating a generic method. This is not what I am looking for.  Normally, a class name would go in  the  .GetAsync<ClassName> part. Not sure if there is a way to insert the class name during run time.

Comment: You have a generic method `GetAsync<T>`, but the type of `T` is only known at runtime. So you have to call `MakeGenericMethod` using with the type `obj.GetType()` as parameter to "create" the correctly typed method at runtime. Afaik the proposed solution should work. If it does not work, please add what you have tried to your question.